# PHP developer, how to solve javascript related issues in a program with millions of line

Tags: php, javascript, debugging

I am expert in PHP. There are some JavaScript related bugs in my
assignment given by my supervisor.  I tried to fix them using Firebug.
It is time consuming.  Is there any other ways?

1. Are there any good IDE's to tackle this issue?
2. Are there any other developer tools except Firebug?

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, `F12` can be useful.  I'm not sure if it's better though.

Comment: Chrome will be a great alternative. Do you any good IDE?. I use PHPStorm

Comment: A Javascript program with millions of lines? I find that statement hard to believe, and to think a company capable of creating such a mess has no standards for debugging them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order:

Narrow the scope.

- Focus on the frontend, forget the backend and PHP for the time being. If javascript bugs are backend related (like AJAX), try mocking the backend (replacing the AJAX calls with something simpler in the test environment).
- Find the module which is buggy. Javascript codebase likes evolving into a code soup when there's no discipline. Debugging is where a clean module separation shines - it's valuable to be able to test a javascript module in isolation.

Write unit tests.

- Reproduce your bugs using automated tests to confirm their existence, make sure your fix works and they don't come back in the future.
- You could use PhantomJS + CasperJS for frontend testing.

Use a debugger (if you still need to).

- Learn what Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools offer you.
- Or try something hot like [trace.gl](https://trace.gl/).
- Don't expect an IDE to be a magic bullet to your problems. When you limit yourself to one tool, you're missing out.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Accepted. Wonderful